# css rotate3d() translate 3d(); not working in firefox and IE11 but working in chrome

Tags: css

css animation transform: rotate3d is working fine in chrome but in firefox and IE11. Its just moving from left to right onmousever in firefox but not flipping like how its working chrome and opera.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: #007bff;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: rotate3d(-10, -10, 1, 360deg) translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Hi!
</div>
```

Comment: May be you should use positive values for the vector in rotate3d . Also, better set transition: transform 0.5s.

Comment: I already tried with positive values but it didn't work. transform 0.5s will not work

Comment: Yes, now I understand the real problem .  Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply to the base state a similar transform, but with the rotation and translation set to zero:  (tested only in FF)

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: #007bff;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: rotate3d(-10, -10, 1,0deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  
}

.box:hover {
  transform: rotate3d(-10, -10, 1, 360deg) translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Hi!
</div>
```